# What is the purpose of the 'hidden_field'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

For example here's a snippit:

```
 <%= form_for [@event, @event.comments.new], html: {class: 'form-horizontal', role: 'form'}, remote: true do |f| %>
            <div><%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %></div>
            <div class="form-group">
```

What is the purpose of the f.hidden_field :user_id, ? Would the code work without it, or is it a necessity to include this line.

Cheers!

Comment: Hidden fields don't show up in page. In your case user_id is passed to the controller action without showing in the view. I assume you are setting the user_id automatically and you don't want the user to change the id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Your Case,you are creating an Event with Comments for a particular User.So the `user_id` is passed as a `hidden_field`.Without it the value for `user_id` will be saved as `nil`,which would resulting an Error.

Comment: Thanks! Understood. To be clear, the user_id field is essentially storing the user that is making the comments id, and associating that particular comment with said user? Always thought the controller handled that...which is why I was a bit confused.

Comment: Assuming that,you have user_id and comment_id in your event,then the event is saved with a comment of respective user.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the controller code which would process the form, the hidden field seems to be holding the id of the user currently logged in.  I assume this would be used in further actions, for example, to attribute the event/comment being created against that user.

The view doesn't need the hidden field, but I would imagine the following controller action would fail if it were removed.

The hidden_field method simply creates `<input ... type="hidden" />` in the html which means the value is included in the form parameters when the form submits, but the value is not visible to the user.